# Samsung A71 Boot Loop / Flash Question

Tags: samsung, rooting, rom-flashing, boot-loop

I have an A71 thats about a year and a half old.  Last week it entered into a boot loop that I can't get it out of.  The only thing I can do that halts the loop is putting it into download mode.  So I tried using Odin and flashed everything (BL, AP, CP, CSC) onto the phone.  When it rebooted, it rebooted back into the loop.  Prior to me doing anything, everyone at Verizon said get a new phone, but I still owe 200 on this one, so I would rather not get a new phone, out of principle if nothing else.  Any thoughts?

Comment: sounds like hardware issue. claim it under warranty or don't pay the bill for this f\*\* s\*\*